# Sqlalchemy python how to query using IN over list of datetime

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy

I would like to filter using a list of timestamps. In SQL the syntax would be like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE.QueryTimestamp IN ("2017-10-20 23:20:00", "2017-10-10 23:20:00")
```

The column QueryTimestamp is datetime in Python.

I tried using following which does not provide correct answers. ts_list is a list of python datetime values.

```
session.query(TABLE).filter(TABLE.QueryTimestamp.in_(ts_list))).all()
```

Comment: I think you should use session.query(TABLE).filter(TABLE.QueryTimestamp.in_(ts_list)).all(). There's an extra ")" in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should filter the result using `or_` operator since these are timestampz.

```
from sqlalchemy import or_, cast
q = session.query(TABLE).filter(
       or_(TABLE.QueryTimestamp == cast("2017-10-20 23:20:00", DateTime), 
           TABLE.QueryTimestamp == cast("2017-10-10 23:20:00", DateTime))
    ).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the required answer by running a count query, where ts_list is a list of datetime elements

```
session.query(TABLE).filter(TABLE.QueryTimestamp.in_(ts_list)).count()
```